# Different objects affect same constructor C++11

Tags: c++11

Having 2 different objects (or instances (I do not know if they have any differences)) of a class, will they instantiate the constructor individually?

For example; Having a constructor that makes a variable `z` equal to 0. A function of the class adds 10 to `z`. So when I use the other object to call the same function, `z` will be 20 (previous value plus 10) or will it be 10 (0+10)?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant code, preferably a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class A and a class B

```cpp
struct A {
  int x = 0;
  void inc() { x+=10; }
};

struct B {
  static int x;
  void inc() { x+=10; }    
};

int B::x = 0;

int main() {
   A a1;
   a1.inc();
   std::cout << a1.x << '\n';

   A a2;
   a2.inc();
   std::cout << a2.x << '\n';

   B b1;
   b1.inc();
   std::cout << b1.x << '\n';

   B b2;
   b2.inc();
   std::cout << b2.x << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
10
10
10
20
```

For instances of `class A` the **member variable** `x` is not shared. Therefore `a1.x` and `a2.x` are both `10` after the respective incrementation.

However, for `class B` the keyword **`static`** declares `x` as a **class variable** that is shared among all instances. So incrementation in what-so-ever instance always increments the class member. After the first incrementation via `b1.inc()`the value of `B::x` is `10` and after the second incrementation via `b2.inc()` the value is `20`.